# SQL to generate sequence number within each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
 PO NO     Acc No    ResultSeqNo
    A1           12          1 
    A1           12          1
    A1           12          1
    A1           12          1
    A2           12          2 
    A2           12          2
    A2           12          2
    A3           13          1
    A3           13          1
    A4           13          2 
    A4           13          2
    A5           14          1
```

In above table, `PONO` and `AccNo` are related, `SeqNo` is nothing but the Counter in the flag. I need to group by `PONo` and `Accno`.

If you see in the above table, `A1` and `A2` has same account number , but all `A1` is considered to be a single group, so the seqNo should be 1 for all `A1`. 
`A2` also has the same acc no as `A1`, but it's a different group, so it should have the seq No 2.

Put another way: for each `AccNo` number, I need to generate sequence numbers by `PO NO`. So for Account #12, all of the `A1` PO NO records have sequence 1, and all of the `A2` PO NO records have sequence 2. For account 13, A3 is 1 and A4 is 2.

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE x 
SET x.ResultSeqNo = x.dr 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT SeqNo,dense_rank() over (order by PO NO) as dr 
    FROM [Purchaseorder] 
    WHERE status = 'In'
  ) x
```

Comment: Answer is `DENSE_RANK`

Comment: I tried using dense_rank,row number , rank  which is not working ....

Comment: How did you use it.. Can you update the question with your code.. I will vote to reopen your question

Comment: UPDATE x SET x.ResultSeqNo = x.dr FROM (SELECT SeqNo,dense_rank() over (order by PO NO) as dr FROM [Purchaseorder] WHERE status = 'In') x                                                                                                       please check the picture , that i how the table looks ,

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `dense_rank` analytic function, but add a `partition by` clause for grouping sets to generate your sequence numbers like:

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY acc_no ORDER BY po_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Here, you need first update resultseqno field so that each row
   uniquely will be identified.
2. I used row_number() window function to number in order resultseqno within partition group
3. I gave an alias to that row_number() fiels as r_num
4. After that I update resultseqno using subquery

   ```
   UPDATE [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] x SET ResultSeqNo=rownum;
   UPDATE [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] x
   SET ResultSeqNo =

   (SELECT b.r_num
   FROM
       (SELECT rownum AS seq_order,
         a.*,
         row_number() over (partition BY Acc_No order by PO_NO) r_num
       FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] a
       ) b
     WHERE x.po_no    =b.po_no
     AND x.ACC_NO     =b.ACC_NO
     AND x.ResultSeqNo=b.ResultSeqNo
     );
   ```